# Is there a good way to share code beween a Rails App and an API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, sinatra, bdd

We have a Rails App and a Sinatra API with separate codebases. They need to work together with the same database.

We can create a record using the API, and then display a page for that record using the Rails app. When creating the record using the API, there are many other records that need to be created at the same time. This all happens fine on the Rails app.

Here's the problem: What is the best way to test that when the API creates the record, all the other records are created and the page renders properly on the Rails app?

I am writing a test in the Rails app for this. Since the API is separate from the Rails app, I can create a mock. But the mock needs to do everything the API would do, so it is not really a mock.

Is it possible (or practical) to include in the Rails app the API file that contains the call to create the record?

Or is there a better way to test for this?

Comment: What do you say about using REST ?

Comment: So do I understand correctly that you have a Rails app and a Sinatra app that exposes an API to Rails, Rails calls the API ... then (and this is the question) does Rails also connect to the database to display or otherwise use or modify the data?  If this is the case, then I would describe this as a single app that happens to have a kind of module (the Sinatra API) for some reason.  It might be fine if the Rails app only reads data and uses API to write, but generally this architecture seems like an accident waiting to happen.  Can you explain a little more about why?

Comment: @Tom - Not quite. The Rails app does not call the API. Yes, Rails also connects to the database to display and modify the data. Why? Because we originally built the Rails app, and gradually discovered we need an API instead.

Comment: @0x90 - this seems to be what Alex is suggesting in his answer. Please see my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have two web applications. That is, two applications that expose a (more or less) public interface on the Net and that respond to HTTP calls.

Why do not use a HTTP client to invoke all of the two servers and perform a complete test (a "workflow test", if you like)?

You can probably use any existing web testing tool for this, or write a test script with any language.

Comment: That's one (good) solution. But then I need to manually start the API, and do tests from the Rails app...that's kind of weird...

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to include in the Rails app a file from the API.

They are hosted on different servers. Even if I got it working on my local machine, it would not work in production.

**EDIT**: Actually, this is not true. If the file only needs to be shared for testing, then it will only run on the local machine (unless there is some kind of CI system). So the production environment doesn't matter. Only the testing (CI) environments matter.